# Startup commands for screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I'd like to set up `screen` to open a specific set of files for editing at startup.

I'd like to have something like this in `~/.screenrc`:

```
chdir /home/andrew/scripts/
screen -t scripts gvim script1.sh
chdir /home/andrew/scratch/
screen -t test
```

I can't seem to get `gvim` to open any files, or my screen to stay alive after the `gvim` opens and detaches.

Comment: `gvim` is a graphical program, are you sure you do not mean `vim`? To get `gvim` to run, you need to supply a valid `DISPLAY` variable, probably set to `:0`. You should be able to do what you ask with: `screen -t scripts DISPLAY=:0 gvim script1.sh`.

Comment: Ideally it would do gvim if possible, and use vim if it couldn't get a display.

Comment: That gives me `Cannot exec 'DISPLAY=': No such file or directory`

Comment: I can fix that by using `setenv` before making the screen, but the screen dies as soon as the gvim detaches.

Comment: Right, I was wrong about prepending variables, that doesn't work here. I can't reproduce the problem you describe, using your `screenrc` file everything runs as expected. I get a `scripts` and a `test` window.

Comment: My `scripts` windows terminates immediately.